# How to connect Relay to a GraphQL server running on different machine?

Tags: reactjs, relay

I have a GraphQL server (express + mongodb). 
I want to connect react relay to my existing GraphQL server which is running on a different machine.

I tried to search for it but no luck. Can any one guide me though ?

Answer (score 3):

Your Relay frontend is independent from the location of your GraphQL backend.

Let's say your GraphQL backend lies here: `http://graphql-backend.demo`

Then you just tell Relay

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://graphql-backend.demo', {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  })
);
```

Remember, your GraphQL backend has to be **Relay specific**!

Docs:
https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html#content
https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html#content